# Scala ActiveRecord performance issue when used with play framework

Tags: database, scala, activerecord, jdbc, playframework-2.0

In my Play application, I tried out [Scala ActiveRecord](https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord) which seems to be a nice orm and claims to have high performance. However, running the following takes 850 ms on an empty database(each query ~425ms):

```
User.findBy("email", "test")
User.findBy("email", "test")
```

Running the same from mysql console takes ~10ms. I would love to use this library, but I can't afford such a low performance. The orm uses [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) for connection management but I couldn't find any advice on how to configure it well.

Do you have any idea what may cause the performance issue?

The generated sql looks like this:

```
Select
  users11.current_country as users11_current_country,
  users11.email as users11_email,
  users11.password_hash as users11_password_hash,
  users11.surname as users11_surname,
  users11.first_name as users11_first_name,
  users11.birth_city as users11_birth_city,
  users11.birth_date as users11_birth_date,
  users11.id as users11_id,
  users11.current_city as users11_current_city,
  users11.birth_country as users11_birth_country
From
  users users11
Where
  (users11.email = ?)
limit 1 offset 0
```

**EDIT**

After further investigation I can tell, the problem might be caused by Play framework. I tested the calls in a non-play environment (simple App), and the response times were 117 and 5 ms for the two queries. However, I also made a test on play's DB.getConnetion() executing a simple SQL query on it, and the result was 2 ms. Is it possible that this is a connection pooling problem?

Squeryl gives similar response times in both environments(play and simple app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, if the User model is as follows:

```scala
case class User(
  @Required var email: String,
  @Required var firstName: String,
  @Required var surname: String
) extends ActiveRecord {
  var currentCountry: String = _
  var birthCity: String = _
  var birthDate: java.util.Date = _
  var birthCountry: String = _

  @Required(on="create")
  @Length(min=8)
  @Confirmation
  @Transient
  var password: String = _

  var passwordConfirmation: String = _

  var passwordHash: String = _

  override def beforeSave() {
    if (password != null && password != "")
      passwordHash = LibraryOfSomething.toHash(password)
  }
}

object User extends ActiveRecordCompanion[User] with PlayFormSupport[User]
```

Used to [`select`](https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord/wiki/Query-interface#select) method:

```
User.where(_.email === "test")
    .select(u => User(u.email, u.firstName, u.surname))
    .headOption
```

Comment: Wow, the culprit was this line:
val passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(plainPassword, BCrypt.gensalt())
So it ran the hash algorithm on each query. I thank you so much. Yesterday I spent my whole day on trying to find out why it worked so slow :( Also, as I can see, you work on the lib. Nice work, thank you for creating it.